# How to avoid memory leak in class function in C++?

Tags: c++

The code below can surely run. My question is I allocated some memory in class function and return a pointer to it. But in main function, I build a new object and assign the pointer to it. But how to release the returned pointer? Do I need to manually do it?

```
#include "stdio.h"

class Complex{

private: 
    float real;
    float imaginary;

public:
    Complex(float, float);
    ~Complex(void) {};
    void set_real(float r);
    void set_imaginary(float i);
    float get_real();
    float get_imaginary();
    Complex* plus(Complex* another);
    Complex* minus(Complex* another);
    Complex* multiply(Complex* another);
};

Complex::Complex(float r, float i){
    this->real = r;
    this->imaginary = i;
}

void Complex::set_real(float r)
{this->real = r;}

void Complex::set_imaginary(float i)
{this->imaginary = i;}

float Complex::get_real() 
{return real;}

float Complex::get_imaginary()
{return imaginary;}

Complex* Complex::plus(Complex* another){
    Complex* result = new Complex(0,0);
    result->set_real(this->real + another->real);
    result->set_imaginary(this->imaginary + another->imaginary);
    return result;
}

Complex* Complex::minus(Complex* another){
    Complex* result = new Complex(0,0);
    result->set_real(this->real - another->real);
    result->set_imaginary(this->imaginary - another->imaginary);
    return result;  
}

Complex* Complex::multiply(Complex* another){
    Complex* result = new Complex(0,0);
    result->set_real((this->real * another->real) - (this->imaginary - another->imaginary));
    result->set_imaginary((this->imaginary*another->real) + (this->real*another->imaginary));
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Complex* c = new Complex(3,4);
    Complex* d = new Complex(6,9);
    Complex* e = new Complex(0,0);

    //will this line bring memory leak? Because all plus function already build a Complex object on leap. I don't know how to release it since I have to return it. 
    e = c->plus(d);

    printf("result is %f + i%f", e->get_real(), e->get_imaginary());

    delete c;
    delete d;
    delete e;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I see a title, and code, where's the description.  What is wrong?  What is the error message?  What do you see?  What did you expect to see?

Comment: Can you avoid using pointers altogether?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your code leaks like mad.  If you absolutely need to return by pointer, return by `std::unique_ptr<Complex>` instead, which is nigh-leak proof.  But your code doesn't  need pointers for anything.

What you probably wanted was more like this:

```
Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex& another){ //pass by const reference
    Complex result = Complex(0,0);
    result.set_real(real + another.real);
    result.set_imaginary(imaginary + another.imaginary);
    return result;
}
```

or more simply:

```
Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex& another){
    return Complex(real + another.real, 
                   imaginary + another.imaginary);
}
```

In C++ we generally pass and return objects "by value" or "by const reference" and don't use pointers a whole lot for function parameters or returns.  Pointers are error-prone.  Passing by value (and using `operator+`) allows this:

```
int main() {
    Complex c = Complex(3,4);
    Complex d = Complex(6,9);
    Complex e = Complex(0,0);
    Complex e = a + b; //magic!  no leaks!
    printf("result is %f + i%f", e.get_real(), e.get_imaginary());
    return 0;
}
```

On unrelated notes:

```
Complex::Complex(float r, float i) 
    :real(r)  //faster for some types.  This is "more correct"
    ,imaginary(i) 
{}

float Complex::get_real() const  //const since it doesn't change anything
{return real;}
```

and finally, in `main`, `return 0` means "everything worked fine" and returning any other value means "something went wrong"

Comment: Great. So informative!! Thanks. I am a java-C++ programmer indeed.

Comment: @ilkahtz: we can tell :D  In general, do not use `thing*`, try to use `std::unique_ptr<thing>` instead.  Far safer.

Comment: Checking out the documents now. Amazing~~!!! :=)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Complex* e = new Complex(0,0);
>
>     //will this line bring memory leak? Because all plus function already build a Complex object on leap. I don't know how to release it
> ```
>
> since I have to return it. 
>           e = c->plus(d);

Yes it will leak.  You first allocate `e` and then you reassign it to point to whatever is returned by your function.  Now the memory you allocated first is lost in space without ever being deallocated. You should do this:

```
Complex* e;
e = e->plus(d);
```

Then there is other issues like, why are you creating `plus` and `minus` functions, when you should really overload `operator+` and `operator-`.

Returning everything by pointer is silly. Just return by value.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of working with all pointers, just return values.

```
Complex* Complex::plus(Complex* another){
    Complex* result = new Complex(0,0);
    result->set_real(this->real + another->real);
    result->set_imaginary(this->imaginary + another->imaginary);
    return result;
}
```

Becomes:

```
Complex Complex::plus(const Complex& another){
    Complex result(0,0);
    result.set_real(real + another.real);
    result.set_imaginary(imaginary + another.imaginary);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your class only contains two floats, I'd be inclined to suggest not using pointers at all (i.e. just return a `Complex`).

This would only be 8 bytes (at least on my system), which is the same size (again, at least on my system) as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your heap allocation, ie dont use new at all.

Transform:

```
Complex* Complex::plus(Complex* another){
    Complex* result = new Complex(0,0);
    result->set_real(this->real + another->real);
    result->set_imaginary(this->imaginary + another->imaginary);
    return result;
}
```

into:

```
Complex Complex::plus(const Complex& another) const{
    Complex result(0,0);
    result.set_real(this.real + another.real);
    result.set_imaginary(this.imaginary + another.imaginary);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Victor Sehr: My only problem with this is while returning it makes a temporary copy of Complex and that may not be efficient depending on how many times this method is called. It may be perfectly fine if saving every ounce of speed isn't an issue.
Alternatively, a refrence may be passed to the method.

Comment: It'd certainly be faster than dynamically allocating memory. You're just adjusting the stack pointer by the size of a Complex, writing a couple of floats to it, and then probably copying it to a register to return it (assuming all of this isn't optimized away).

Comment: @Sid Well calling `new` will certainly be orders of magnitude slower than copying two floats.

Comment: @ChristianRau Agreed. But how about passing a reference as a parameter for the result.

Comment: @Sid I guess any possible performance difference will be removed by any optimizing/inlining/copy-eliding compiler anyway and if it's not inlined, then you also have a reference argument to copy. All in all I guess there won't be any difference (maybe a single instruction or something in that order of magnitude). Whereas I'm usually not somebody who cries "help, premature optimization!" all the time, in this case it certainly is, considering the huge useability gain of operator overloading and the just negligable performance gains (if any) of passing a reference.

Comment: @Sid Of course matters are different for types that are not just the size of a pointer/reference. But then again in this case r-value references and move-semantics (or maybe even simple pre-11 copy elision) can make the above applicable there, too.

Comment: @ChristianRau Are you saying that 

Complex add(...) { Complex x; ...; return x;}
and
complex x;
add(x);
void add(Complex & x) {...; return x;}

are the same? I think in a system with very high load I would definitely prefer the latter.

Comment: @Sid Sorry, I can't get your code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

```
e = c->plus(d);
```

will cause a leak, because the Complex pointed to by e is not freed before the new pointer to the new Complex is assigned.

Despite the fact, that the STL has a `template <typename T> class complex;`

```
#include <complex>
```

you can implement a member function for arithmetic returning values:

```
Complex Complex::plus(const Complex& another)const{
    Complex result(0,0);
    result.set_real(this->real + another.real);
    result.set_imaginary(this->imaginary + another.imaginary);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use auto_ptr or a similar smart ptr.

Alternatively, you could also pass in a reference to the result objects in your plus or minus methods instead of a pointer that needs to be allocated. In other words, handle memory outside the class module.

Comment: The use of new/delete here is superfluous.  Regular stack declarations should be used not smart pointers.

Comment: Your alternative suggestion isn't really any better than your first suggestion. Don't make things even worse for Java-C++ prgrammers by showing them that there exists something that just cleans up their memory for them, so they are free to spam smart pointers everywhere, like in simple value type operators.

Answer (score 0):

The (one?) problem is that you're allocating an 'e' pointer and then re-assigning the pointer later to the results of the add().  Inside the add function it's already creating a new Complex object to return.

So to fix this, in main you shouldn't be allocating E ahead of time.

[or you could restructure the code to use copy/assignments too]